# icpc debug info with Eigen library

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, eigen, icc

Eigen is a popular C++ library, but icpc seems to have a problem generating debugging info from code that uses Eigen.  I'm using the compiler icpc version 13.1.1.  I checked with both Eigen 3.2.8 and 3.1.3.  It's going to be hard to recompile all the libraries I need with another compiler, so does anyone see a good solution to get Eigen to work with a debugger?

The problem is that variable values don't always get updated in the debugger.  Here is main.cpp

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "/home/mylogin/include/Eigen/Core"
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    printf("Starting main\n");
    double mytest = 3.0;
    // If the next line is commented out, the debugger works
    Eigen::Vector3d v(1,2,3);
    printf("This is mytest %f \n",mytest);
    return 0;
}
```

I compile with

```
icpc -O0 -debug -I/home/mylogin/include/ main.cpp
```

Then you can run the debugger

```
idbc ./a.out 
Intel(R) Debugger for applications running on Intel(R) 64, Version 13.0, Build [80.215.23]
------------------ 
object file name: ./a.out 
Reading symbols from /mnt/io1/home/mylogin/a.out...done.
(idb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4005fb: file     /mnt/io1/home/mylogin/main.cpp, line 142.
(idb) run
Starting program:     /mnt/io1/home/mylogin/a.out
[New Thread 18379 (LWP 18379)]
Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fff8b2e89b8) at /mnt/io1/home/mylogin/main.cpp:8
8               printf("Starting main\n");
(idb) next
Starting main
11              Eigen::Vector3d v(1,2,3);
(idb) next
12              printf("This is mytest %f \n",mytest);
(idb) next
This is mytest 3.000000 
13             return 0;
(idb) print mytest
$1 = 5.9415882155426741e-313
```

You see in the last few lines that the executable prints "3.0" correctly.  You also see that the variable is not printed correctly by the debugger.

Both gdb and idbc show the problem.  It doesn't seem to be because it's near the start or end of the function main().  The CPU is

```
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2650 0 @ 2.00GHz
```

Linux version is

```
Description:    Scientific Linux release 6.4 (Carbon)
```

Thanks for ideas!

Comment: Have you tried newer icc? Now the version is 16.0.3. Yours seems too old.

Comment: I may try that but I will need to recompile many other libraries and then re-test them all.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having the same problem...

Comment: I had to stop investigating and move on.  I was surprised that [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php) hadn't released a statement about the problem.