# Eigen::Matrix shows wrong values in debugger

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging, qt-creator, eigen

When debugging my code that uses the Eigen library (Version 3.3.3), I get incorrect values for the values contained in the matrices, even for simplest code:

```
    Eigen::Vector2d test(1.0, -120.0);
```

I get:

[image: weird doubles...]

This happens consistenly in my code.

I am code built as RelWithDebugInfo in MSVC2010 and the QtCreator debugger.

[This person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38205285/icpc-debug-info-with-eigen-library) seems to have the same problem, unfortunately, nobody had an answer.

Thanks!

Comment: Probably due to optimizations. RelWithDebugInfo is not "perfect" for debugging.

Comment: Are you running the release or debug version of your compiled code?

Comment: Especially, for very simple code the compiler may not allocate actual memory (or initialize it) at all, if it sees that the variable is not used at all. Try compiling in pure "debug" mode. For bigger projects, try compiling with only mild optimizations enabled (I don't know how to configure MSVC for that).

Comment: Another possibility (sometimes) is to store your variable in a `volatile` variable. But of course, you should avoid that for production code as well.

Comment: @AviGinsburg: Unfortunately, for reason out of my control, I can't run the project in debugging mode... RelWithDebugInf is the best I will get. I was hoping that I could manually turn off optimizations in Eigen, for example

Comment: Can't you create a small test program and compile it as debug?

Comment: Are you sure you stopped your program after the initialisation of the variable. Normally QtCreator shows `optimised out` when the variable is not available due to compiler optimisation.